# node js async.map attempt is failing with empty result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

**Background Information**

This is my first attempt at node... and now the async module. I'm having a hard time making synchronous calls to my redis database.

**Goal**
Ultimately, what I need to happen is when a user calls my REST API's GET method, I want to return json object that looks like this:

```
 [ { '10.123': '1111111111' },
  { '10.126': '2222222222' },
  { '10.125': '3333333333' },
  { '10.222': '4444444444' },
  { '10.131.90': '5555555555' },
  { '10.18': '6666666666' },
  { '10.19': '7777777777' },
  { '10.44': '8888888888' } ]
```

The keys you see above are queried using the SCAN command in the main GET method.  And then for each key returned by the redis SCAN, I turn around and run an "HGETGALL" command to find out the values you see above

**Problem**

Although the queryhgetall function is correctly being called once per key returned in the main GET method... the return the data from this method is empty.  Here's my code:

**Code**

```
25 //async test start ====================================================================================
 26 var async = require('async');
 27 
 28 var queryhgetall = function (redis_key, doneCallBack) {
 29         var tempObject = {};
 30         redis.hgetall(redis_key, function (err, data) {
 31                 if (err) {
 32                         console.log("hgetall method fails: " + err);
 33                 }
 34                 if (data) { 
 35                         var key = redis_key.split(":");
 36                         tempObject[key[1]]=data.callerid;
 37                         console.log(tempObject);
 38                 }       
 39         });
 40         return doneCallBack(null,tempObject);
 41 };
 42 
 43 router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
 44     redis.send_command("SCAN", [0, "MATCH", "emergency:*"], function (err, reply) {
 45         if (reply) {
 46             var retdata = [];
 47             async.map(reply[1], queryhgetall, function (err, results) {
 48                 console.log("finished");
 49                 console.log("results start");
 50                 console.log(results);
 51                 console.log("results stop");
 52             });
 53             }
 54      });    
 55 });  
 56 
 57 //async test finish =====================================================================================================
```

**Code Output**

Here's what I see in the console output:

```
GET /emergency/ - - ms - -
finished
results start
[ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ]
results stop
{ '10.123': '1111111111' }
{ '10.126': '2222222222' }
{ '10.125': '3333333333' }
{ '10.222': '4444444444' }
{ '10.131.90': '5555555555' }
{ '10.18': '6666666666' }
{ '10.19': '7777777777' }
{ '10.44': '8888888888' }
```

As you can see from the output, the console.log command on line 37 proves that i've correctly queried the callerid value for each key, but the way I'm returning this data to the GET method is perhaps incorrect, because everything is empty.

Can you tell me what I'm missing? I was trying to follow the example here: 
http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/06/think-async/

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I changed this:

```
 28 var queryhgetall = function (redis_key, doneCallBack) {
 29         var tempObject = {};
 30         redis.hgetall(redis_key, function (err, data) {
 31                 if (err) {
 32                         console.log("hgetall method fails: " + err);
 33                 }
 34                 if (data) { 
 35                         var key = redis_key.split(":");
 36                         tempObject[key[1]]=data.callerid;
 37                         console.log(tempObject);
 38                 }       
 39         });
 40         return doneCallBack(null,tempObject);
 41 };
```

to this:

```
 28 var queryhgetall = function (redis_key, doneCallBack) {
 29         var tempObject = {};
 30         redis.hgetall(redis_key, function (err, data) {
 31                 if (err) {
 32                         console.log("hgetall method fails: " + err);
 33                 }
 34                 if (data) { 
 35                         var key = redis_key.split(":");
 36                         tempObject[key[1]]=data.callerid;
 37                         console.log(tempObject);
 38                         return doneCallBack(null, tempObject);
 39                 }
 40         });
 41 //      console.log(tempObject);
 42 //      return doneCallBack(null,tempObject);
 43 };
```

Comment: thanks jason.  yeah, i think you posted just after i did... or very close to it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `return doneCallBack` up inside the other function like line 38-39 so it will wait for redia data before calling callback.